# BLE connection between Android and PC

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create a project where a mobile Android device is connecting via BLE to a USB dongle inserted in a normal PC (Windows and Linux).

For Android I see good support in the API to establish this connection.
It's not clear for me how to read the data sent from Android on the PC (from a C/Java/Anything program).

At the first look there is no easy way to start a "server" on the PC to listen for BLE connections.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Linux: - BLENO. Windows - only Win 10. Not all hardware is supprted. You have to find dongle that will work. WinRT API (or Bluetooth Framework).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For BLE, you'll need to decide which side is the peripheral and which is the master.

On the PC side, I know of the good old `bluez` library (http://www.bluez.org), written in C and readily available on Linux.  For windows, I suspect that there are similar toolkits.

`bluez-tools` can help you run test at the command line: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96693/connect-to-a-bluetooth-device-via-terminal